# how to charge per minute with paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

been searching for answer but can't seem to find out. I'm charged with setting up a web-site that will give 24hr help/support billed at x$ for 15mins. We would like this to happen in teh background as much as possible.

So far I can only find daily, monthly recurring charges in paypal. Is it possible, or does anyone know of a method, to do this with the paypal API?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - if all you need to support is credit card - just use the new Restful Vault and Payment APIs. Vault API to collect and store your customer's credit card details, and Payments API to charge their card as and when you need. Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

IF you want to support PayPal accounts- unfortunately the new APIs do not yet support this feature but the classic APIs do support it. Adaptive Payments API provides you with a preapproval functionality that let's you collect a preapproval from your customer and then charge them as and when you need. Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/